# How to display multiple variables of matrix and array using a single command in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, printf, octave, display, disp

```
a = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10];
b = [1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9];
c = zeros(3,1);`
d = rand([4 1],'single');
```

or

```
d = rand([4 1],'double');
e = transpose(b);
f = pinv(e);
g = e*e;
h = [0:100];
i = [0:100:1000];
```

Use display command or `fprintf` to display the above 9 variables.

Comment: `disp(a), disp(b), ...` maybe?

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you wanted, but this line will display all your workspace variables values: `cellfun(@eval,who);`. If you have a lot of and/or large variables it will take a while...

Comment: Question is not specific enough.  What kind of output do you want to see?  Each variable separately?

Answer (score 0):

You could add them into a temporary struct, which will then print its fields and their contents on screen:

```
struct('a', a, 'b', b, 'c', c, 'd', d, 'e', e, 'f', f, 'g', g, 'h', h, 'i', i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10];
b = [1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9];
c = zeros(3,1);
d = rand([4 1],'single'); 

A = cell(4,1) ;
A{1} =a ;
A{2} = b ;
A{3} = c ;
A{4} = d ;
```